# Cannot enroll in Apple Developer program

Tags: developer-program

I have been meaning to finish my developer account and sign up for the iOS program, and since WWDC2015 just happened, I thought no better time than now.

Unfortunately, when I go to enroll, I am told

> "Sorry, you can’t enroll at this time."

I figured this might have to do with me being under 18, however, I have set up a corporation so I can bypass this roadblock. Furthermore, when I started to sign up previously, I had no issues up until this point.

Is this a side-effect of WWDC? What can I do?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this error. I have contacted developer support. They suggested verifying my information associated with my Apple ID and trying a new browser, but that didn't work. In the email I sent to them I included a link to this thread, so hopefully some answers will come this way.

Comment: I know this is old but I figured I would chime in. Given answers are blocked on this question the best I can do is add a comment.  The issue is most definitely that your Apple ID is marked as under 18 (due to the specified birthdate).  As an individual, Apple do not let you enrol unless you are over 18.  It is not clear on their website but I proved that this is the case by changing the birthdate on the Apple ID and it immediately allowed enrolment..

Answer (score 4):

I imagine that during WWDC the demand for dev accounts is higher than usual, and also that most of the people at Apple who would normally look into any problems with the developer program are likely to be at WWDC themselves.

Try again next week?

Comment: Alright, thanks! I also believe they don't want a bunch of non-developers signing up, only to get their hands on iOS 9...