# Does Apple have administrative control over Developer program enrollment?

Tags: apple-id, app-store-connect, enterprise

I have tried for 2 weeks to complete enrollment in the [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) (US$ 299), but halfway through each attempt (10-12 by last count) the application switches from **Enterprise** to **Developer** (US$ 99).

Is there any **administrative override** for this program? I have re-applied 15-20 times by now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Remember that we’re not customer support for Apple. 15 rejections should probably clue you in to the need to start with the normal account - but I’ll explain in an answer

Comment: To comment on your own question and be able to edit it without approval, you can use the same account you used to ask the question. To regain access to an account or merge multiple accounts, use the [contact us](https://apple.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - Apple has very good administrative control and you deal with the sales organization (online web store) when you are purchasing any developer account. They aren’t going to know the in-and-out of why you were rejected a bunch of times but they are showing you clearly the way forward.

1. Pay the $99
2. Get your account going now
3. Upload your first two or three apps to TestFlight and get your testing going with hundreds of internal beta testers.

Then engage the developer support team for free once they can see the sort of work you’re doing and when you have a specific need the basic account can’t meet. Now you’re a known partner they can work with - now you’re the guy keeping on banging on the sales door that was closed again and again. True enterprises are easy to verify and when Apple isn’t sure you are an enterprise, their job is to say no and reject the application so don’t get mad at the process or the people - just level up your goals and build your app now and work with developer support down the road - once they see your need, they will be your advocate so sales arrange an upgrade and/or pro-rated refund if you really need to get to enterprise features before the first year expires.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/enroll/

Since the test flight restrictions are so lenient now, you won’t need enterprise to distribute apps to hundreds of employees with the $99 program.

The enterprise account is really for people that start with a normal developer account and need added functionality. If you haven’t had one to two years of experience in the developer paid programs and are not actually an enterprise - I would strongly discourage you from going for the enterprise program out of the gate. You simply don’t need it to get going in my experience.

- [How to appeal rejection by Apple for Developer Enterprise Account?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283799/)
- [I tried to enroll my company to Apple Enterprise program, but get message "Cannot enroll in Apple Developer program"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276988/)

Comment: I am not very sure, but it may be the case that an enterprise program membership pre-requires an organisation to be enrolled in a regular developer program. Nothing like this is documented though.

Comment: @NimeshNeema It’s certainly not required, but I’ve seen dozens of small teams shoot for the enterprise rings when they can do all the development they need now for free and then with $99. See the linked questions - enterprise accounts have high risk of abuse - so they get lots of scrutiny - if you are an enterprise, you will have teams of people to do all the paperwork and are easy for Apple to verify.

Comment: Yes, gone though the answers. Very valid points. I wasn't aware of the enterprise program account abuses.

Answer (score -1):

Apple offer no access to executive levels of administrators.

Comment: Richard welcome to Ask Different. Your answer is a great first step, but it's very short and doesn't give much explanation. Could you consider expanding your question a bit.

Comment: What even is “an executive level of administrators”? We have amazing professional support from Apple at work and a clear escalation path for consumers.